# existing foreign key that references fields with different datatype (char(8) and varchar(8))

Tags: sql-server

This is more a quest for information that a request for help...

I'm upgrading some old databases (running on sql 2005 and compatibility level 70, I suspect they are online since sql 6.5) to get rid of a couple of old servers and deploy SQL Server 2012 or 2014.

I had to deal with some sql collation now unsupported so I dropped some indexes and foreign keys. While trying to restore them I've been stopped by this error:

> Msg 1778, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
>  Column 'dbo.Table1.IDColumn' is
>   not the same data type as referencing column
>   'Table2.ColumnFK' in foreign key
>   'Foreign_key'.

The first field is declared as `varchar(8)` and the second is a `char(8)` so the message is correct.

I'm doing all the tests on a copy so I double checked on the production database and the foreign key is there, linking a `char` field with a `varchar` field.

When scripting the constraint this is what I got (that's the script that is giving error):

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table2]
WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Foreign_key]
FOREIGN KEY([ColumnFK]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Table1] ([IDColumn])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table2]
NOCHECK CONSTRAINT [Foreign_key]
GO
```

I found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308969/add-relationship-for-columns-with-different-data-types) on SO stating that it is not possible to have a foreign key using 2 columns that have different datatype but a workaround is supplied so the issue is not critical.

The question is: was it ever allowed to create a relationship on fields with different data types without tricks? Was there some sort of 'compatibility' between char and varchar?

The answer should be a obvious 'yes, it is possible' but I can't find any evidence stating that this behavior is (was?) allowed and/or expected: I have the foreign key in place but it should not be possible to create it.

Comment: Neither 2008 nor 2014 accepts foreign key between char and varchar (according to sqlfiddle). Whether this was legal in earlier version of sqlserver I don't no, but many other DBMS accepts it, so I would not be surprised if it once where accepted.

Comment: I'm making my mind to install nt4 with sql 6.5 just to check...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Digging into long forgotten boxes I found both nt4 and SQL-Server 6.5 installation media and I can confirm that a foreign key referencing fields with different data types was allowed.

Here is the statement I successfully run on SQL-Server 6.5:

```
create table tbl1 (code char(8) primary key (code))
create table tbl2 (code varchar(8) primary key (code))
alter table tbl1 add constraint FK foreign key (code) references tbl2 (code)
```

no trailing semicolon or you'll get a syntax error.

I can't get a grasp on sql 7 media so I can't tell if it was working on that version too.

Comment: Interesting! Was it allowed for a `char(8)` to reference a `char(9)`? A `char(9)` to reference a `char(8)`? A `varchar` to reference a `nvarchar`?

Comment: This was indeed a breaking change from 6.5 to 7. See http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/migrating-sql-server-65-70. I have no idea how long compatibility was maintained. Probably as long as 6.5 database compatibility. SQL Server 7 installation media is hard to find because it was withdrawn due to Java licencing issues.

Comment: @PaulWhite - Yep this test on 2005 shows it was preserved that long  http://i.stack.imgur.com/2w7cj.png (2005 supported 60/ 65/70, 2008 just 80 up)

Comment: @ypercube - From testing on 2005 with 6/6.5 compatibility mode this would not be allowed `Columns participating in a foreign key relationship must be defined with the same length.`

Comment: I still haven't found what i'm looking for [cit]: documentation about this change on msdn. Does anyone has a link?

Comment: @Paolo - You'd be looking for "breaking changes" in the release notes for SQL Server 7 but I don't think much documentation is online for SQL Server prior to 2000.